# Object [object Object] has no method 'footable'

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins, footable

I plan to use the [footable jQuery](https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable) plugin for my tables to make them responsive, but I fail to integrate it into my website. This is my CSS:

```
<link href="FooTable-2/css/footable.core.css?v=2-0-1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="FooTable-2/css/footable.metro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="FooTable-2/js/footable.js?v=2-0-1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="FooTable-2/js/footable.sort.js?v=2-0-1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="FooTable-2/js/footable.filter.js?v=2-0-1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="FooTable-2/js/footable.paginate.js?v=2-0-1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="build/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.footable').footable();
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table class="footable">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Nummer</th>
  <th>Vorname</th>
  <th>Nachname</th>
  <th>Adresse</th>
  <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Telefon</th>
  <th>E-Mail</th>
  <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Geburtstag</th>
  <th>Kundentyp</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
```

Error:

```
$('.footable').footable(); 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'footable'
```

Console:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Make sure your script references are correct. Check the network tab of your browser dev tools for 404 errors.

Comment: Clearly, the plug-in isn't getting loaded. You should have other errors in the console telling you why.

Comment: No 404 errors. I checked that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some kind of a conflict between `application.js` (Bootstrap 3.0) and `footable.js`. I rearranged the order of the includes and was able to resolve the problem:

`application.js` is now included as the first script:

```
<script src="build/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After that, I included all FooTable scripts and CSS files:

```
<link href="FooTable-2/css/footable.core.css?v=2-0-1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="FooTable-2/css/footable.metro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="FooTable-2/js/footable.js?v=2-0-1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="FooTable-2/js/footable.sort.js?v=2-0-1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="FooTable-2/js/footable.filter.js?v=2-0-1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="FooTable-2/js/footable.paginate.js?v=2-0-1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```